# Raising text inside a textview

Tags: android, xml

This is a simple question but its kicking my butt all around xml land.

All I want to do is to have the two edit text fields separated by a colon and to have the colon be centered like the following:
00:30

Right now when it displays the colon is slightly lower than the 00 and 30 of the edit text fields

I have tried using `android:layout_marginBottom= "10dp"` but that doesn't work.  Any ideas?  Thanks

Here is my code:

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_minute"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="85dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text_minute"
        android:layout_marginLeft="45sp"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:text="@string/edit_minute"
        android:textColor="#0D4F8B"
        android:textSize="70sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

     <TextView
          android:id="@+id/text_colon"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/edit_minute"
          android:layout_below="@+id/text_minute"
          android:textAlignment="center"
          android:text="@string/text_colon"
          android:textSize="70sp"
          android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_second"
        android:layout_width="105dp"
        android:layout_height="85dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text_minute"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/text_colon"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:text="@string/edit_second"
        android:textColor="#0D4F8B"
        android:textSize="70sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Comment: The three views must be centered horizontally?

Comment: I believe the problem might be with the textSize being so large which boosts up the 00 and the 30 above the edit text line below it but since the : doesn't have a line it ends up being lower.  I put a empty textView below the : and then set the 'android:layout_above="@+id/empty_textView' so now it lines up

Comment: Yes but are you sure this will work on any screen? Maybe try using layout_alignTop and layout_alignBottom as I suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put Layout_height of Both edittext to wrapcontent without giving a specific height then the three views would be aligned.....

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_minute"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text_minute"
        android:layout_marginLeft="45sp"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:text="08"
        android:textColor="#0D4F8B"
        android:textSize="70sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

     <TextView
          android:id="@+id/text_colon"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/edit_minute"
          android:layout_below="@+id/text_minute"
          android:textAlignment="center"
          android:text=":"
          android:textSize="70sp"
          android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_second"
        android:layout_width="105dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text_minute"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/text_colon"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:text="30"
        android:textColor="#0D4F8B"
        android:textSize="70sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I would first put them all in a `RelativeLayout`, and place this layout under "text_minute".

Then in the following I centered all, and the colon's height is adjusted using the attributes `layout_alignTop` and `layout_alignBottom` that force the `TextView` to follow the first `EditText` height:

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/text_minute" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_minute"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="85dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/text_colon"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:text="@string/edit_minute"
    android:textColor="#0D4F8B"
    android:textSize="70sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

 <TextView
      android:id="@+id/text_colon"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:textAlignment="center"
      android:layout_alignTop="@+id/edit_minute"
      android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/edit_minute"
      android:gravity="center_horizontal"
      android:text="@string/text_colon"
      android:textSize="70sp"
      android:textStyle="bold" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_second"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="85dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/text_colon"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:text="@string/edit_second"
    android:textColor="#0D4F8B"
    android:textSize="70sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Unfortuantly it still shows lower.  I am pretty sure that it has to do with the edit text vs text view... the line below the edit text field boost up the 00 and the 30

Answer (score 0):

You can place your EditText TextView and EditText all in a LinearLayout and use android:baselineAligned and android:baselineAlignedChildIndex.

If you require your parent view is a RelativeLayout then you can use android:layout_alignBaseline on each of the child views.